# How to form Firestore query matching with undefined elements

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to perform the following query with Firebase's Firestore:

```
async function getTicketNumbers(companyID) {

    var ticketNumbers = []

    const docs = await store
        .collection('ABC')
        .doc(companyID)
        .collection('DEF')
        .where('ticketStatus', 'in', ['scheduled', undefined])
        .get()

    if (docs) {
        docs.forEach(doc => {
            ticketNumbers.push(doc.id)
        })
    }

    return ticketNumbers
}
```

The problem in my code is the `undefined` keyword. But how can I perform a query where `TicketStatus` is either `scheduled` or `undefined`?

I also tried `null` and empty string `''`, what does not result in an error, but does not return additional documents.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no "undefined" value for Cloud Firestore fields.  The valid types can be seen in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).  You can see that null is a valid field value, but not undefined.

If you're trying to query for fields that don't exist at all, that is not possible.  Firestore can only search for fields participating in an index, and a lack of a field means a lack of indexing.  You will have to arrange for every document to have a field with some value if you want it to be queryable.